# ¿Cómo pudo hacer para que mi Navbar vertical (que está en mi <Header>) TAPE el contenido de mi <Main>?

Tags: css, css3, scss

Quiero lograr que mi Navbar Vertical tape el Input Label de mi Main.
Es decir, que si yo coloco cualquier etiqueta, en este caso el input, sea tapado por el navbar.
¿Será posible?

**HTML:**

```
<header>
                        <a href="#" class="icon icon--linkedin">
                            <i class="fas fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i>
                            <span class="nav-item">LinkedIn</span>
                        </a>
</header>
    <main>
        <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" required>
            <label>Enter text here</label>
        </div>
    </main>
```

**CSS:**

```
nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: #1A1D24;
    width: 210px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: width 0.2s linear;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
main{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #060b23;
}
```

Comment: ¿Por que simplemente no le pones un `display:none;`?